# How to patch a deployment with an additional container using ansible modules?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, openshift

Using Ansible module k8s , how can we patch a deployment with an additional container.

I would like to understand how can we achieve a patch to the below deployment using ansible modules:

```
Initial dpeloyment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: patch-demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: patch-demo-ctr
        image: nginx
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: dedicated
        value: test-team
```

Patch with:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: patch-demo-ctr-2
        image: redis
```

How can I perform this action using an ansible module?

```
kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-file.yaml)"
```